# How do i make my calculator to show each buttons value upon click in the display?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
    <title>
        Calculator
    </title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="calculator">

        <button class="num">0</button>
        <button class="num">1</button>
        <button class="num">2</button>
        <button class="num">3</button>
        <button class="num">4</button>
        <button class="num">5</button>
        <button class="num">6</button>
        <button class="num">7</button>
        <button class="num">8</button>
        <button class="num">9</button>
        <button class="op">+</button>
        <button class="op">-</button>
        <button class="op">*</button>
        <button class="op">/</button>
        <button class="op">=</button>
        <div id="display">0</div>
    </div>

    <script src="calculator.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to build a calculator from the Project : calculator in the odin project. I have all these buttons and a display which will display the value of the button on the display. How do i go on to do that? i have tried doing the following but it doesnt work out :

```
let listOf = document.querySelectorAll('num');
listOf.ForEach((num), () => {
  num.addEventListener('click', () => {
    res.textContent = num.nodeValue; // above,let res = document.getElementbyId('display');) 
  })
})
```

Comment: You're syntax and formatting are invalid. Moreover, your question is very broad. I suggest running your code, seeing what the errors are, trying to resolve them yourself, and, only if that fails, asking specific questions on SO.

Comment: @junvar Alright, so i tried doing a classic for loop too and that didnt work out either. I dont know what am i doing wrong. can you give some tips on error detection? is it because i dont have the concepts jotted down perfectly or what? i feel like c++ was way easier to get used to than JS ;)

Comment: @junvar your*. I think his problem is clear, he explained he is trying to make a calculator which showed his effort and yes he forgot to post his error output. He is a new user which with help will improve in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The query to get all the buttons of class `num` is incorrect. To select all the elements by their class, use dot `.`. You can see more selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
2. Use innerHTML to set/get their "inner html" value (I wouldn't recommend this approach though)
3. You can use the same solution for the elements of class `op`

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.num');
for (let i=0; i< buttons.length; i++){
  let button = buttons[i];
  button.addEventListener('click' , () => {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += button.innerHTML
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
    <button class="num">0</button>
    <button class="num">1</button>
    <button class="num">2</button>
    <button class="num">3</button>
    <button class="num">4</button>
    <button class="num">5</button>
    <button class="num">6</button>
    <button class="num">7</button>
    <button class="num">8</button>
    <button class="num">9</button>
    <button class="op">+</button>
    <button class="op">-</button>
    <button class="op">*</button>
    <button class="op">/</button>
    <button class="op">=</button>
    <div id="display">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for saving the day, i have been stuck on this for several hours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and don't forget to upvote :)